# Taking a screenshot of a view

Tags: iphone, ios

How does one take a screenshot of a view with code?

I have read on some forums and there was a post made by an apple engineer and the code didnt work.

Is there a built in way to do this or what is the correct way to screenshot a view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple just updated Technical Q&A QA1703 [Screen Capture in UIKit Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html).  I just put this in my code and it works well.

Comment: Yeah I JUST found it after asking this question. it wasnt working a while back. but I tested it now and yeah. works well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can let the layer of the view render into a `CGContextRef`. This would be something like this:

```
[[myView layer] renderInContext:someContext];
```

You can then get the UIImage representation of the context and save it or so. However, please remark that this is kind of slow as the whole layer plus it sublayers have to be rendered again into the new context.

Don't forget to include and link against QuartCore for this.

Comment: Like Black Frog mentioned, apple updated their code and it works really well. instant screenshot.

Comment: @Helium3: Well, its the very same way as I suggested, only copy'n'pasteable.

Comment: @Helium3: Well, try to render a 1024x1024 UIScrollView with a few large images, and then evaluate again if its slow or not ;)